# How create window to send email?

Tags: c#, winforms, smtp

I want to create a button and when user click on that, a window form will open and the From is default text, "To" is also load from code behind and user can edit that text, "Content" is default text and user can edit too.

So now I can send email with:

```
System.Net.Mail.MailMessage mail = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("gw1.scei.a-star.edu.sg");

mail.From = new MailAddress("mydefaultemail");
mail.To.Add("the To emails will be input here");
mail.Subject = "Test Mail";
mail.Body = "This is for testing SMTP mail.";

SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("mydefaultemail", "");

SmtpServer.Send(mail);
```

Now I don't know how could I make it to be wildows form and catch the text in that form to input into this code?

Answer (score 0):

You add a textbox to your Windows form.

Then, in your code, you get the text property value of that textbox and set your email variable accordingly.

```
mail.Body = myTextBox.Text;
```

Comment: Could you be more specify ? I don't know how to have text box with "To", "From", "Subject", "Content" fields like that?

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ew6tzdt(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Yes, Im using VS. Can it be created using code behind? And how to link it with button click so that when user click a button "Send Email" it will open the form and then can edit then send?

Comment: I don't know why I cannot use messagebox. like: MessageBox.Show(this.inputText.Text); there will be error using messagebox

Answer (score 0):

```
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
            client.Port = 587;
            client.EnableSsl = true;
            client.Timeout = 100000;
            client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(
            "yourid@gmail.com", "yourgmailpassword");
            MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
            msg.To.Add("Send To email Id");
            msg.From = new MailAddress("yourid@gmail.com");
            msg.Subject ="Subject";
            msg.Body = "Message";              
            client.Send(msg);
```

Comment: how to create that textbox thing ?

Comment: I don't have problem sending email automatically, with the code I used above, it works fine. However I want when user click it open a window or textbox, whatever, with "To", "From", "Subject", "Content" then I can parse this to pass the my sending email code above.